# Calling a function in program from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, dictionary

I am learning Python starting with 2.7 and working with a dictionary, wanted to execute a function in my program when the key is called. Looked on the net quite a bit, but either is not related or may just simply not understanding. Below is what I started doing as a concept while using one of my favorite games to learn.

Below is a more accurate representation of where I am currently at:

```
myDict = {
    'descript': "This is some text to be printed",
    'NORTH': northOfHouse (not sure if this is correct format)
    }

def westOfHouse():

    print myDict['descript]

    if action == ('n' or 'north'):
        myDict['NORTH]() (Not sure about proper format)
    else:
        print "there is no path in that direction
```

I have gotten the basic stuff to work when using a dictionary such as printing strings, modifying values, etc... just not getting how to make functions execute.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Using a dictionary to select function to execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168340/python-using-a-dictionary-to-select-function-to-execute)

Comment: You're calling currently `myDef` *when creating the dictionary*, did you actually want something like `myDict['key']()` to work?

Comment: `'key': myDef()`. You're immediately calling the function inside the dictionary. Remove the parentheses.

Comment: calling looking up the value to a given key in a python dictionary returns the value associated with that key. This object can be a function no problem, however you then need to tell it to execute by calling it like `myResult = myDict[key](<parameters>)`.

Comment: I am wanting to, if possible, to call a function that is identified in the dictionary and then go to that function in the program and execute its code..if that makes more sense.

Comment: when setting a key:value such as:  'NORTH': northOfhouse , I get name not defined. I also tried 'NORTH': northOfHouse() . So 1) not sure what the proper identification of a function should look like in a dictionary, and 2) how to properly call the key:value from the program. I have seen what Chris has posted with the myResult = myDict[key](<parameters>), but could not make it work

Comment: `northOfHouse` needs to be the name of a callable, like a function, so you can call it if the `action` matches.

Comment: Once you've defined `northOfHouse`, the rest of what you're doing looks basically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a very simplified demo of what it you are attempting to do, look at the following:

```
def northOfHouse():
    print "north"
    action = raw_input()
    myDict[action]()
def westOfHouse():
    print "west"
    action = raw_input()
    myDict[action]()

myDict = {
    "WEST": westOfHouse,
    "NORTH": northOfHouse
}

action = raw_input()
myDict[action]()
```

First I've defined 2 functions (`northOfHouse` and `westOfHouse`).  Each of this functions will simply print there location and ask for a new input.  They will then attempt to call the function for the given input in the dictonary.

Next I define the dictionary, in my case using the keys `"WEST"` and `"NORTH"` to **reference** the correct functions(note that I'm not calling the functions).  These can then be called using the appropriate `myDict["WEST"]()` or `myDict["NORTH"]()` as you would expect.

Using this it's possible to enter `"NORTH"` and `"WEST"` and see the appropriate function being called, this can obviously be expanded to what you want to do (with the inclusion of appropriate input validation and performing these instructions on a loop basis rather than recursively of course as with the code provided, recursion depth errors will haunt you after too long).

Another thing I'd recommend is to return a dictionary from each function, that way the current location determines where you can move to next:

```
def northOfHouse():
    print "You're in the NORTH of the house\nYou can go 'WEST'"
    myDict = {
        "WEST": westOfHouse
    }
    return myDict

def westOfHouse():
    print "You're in the WEST of the house\nYou can go 'NORTH'"
    myDict = {
        "NORTH": northOfHouse
    }
    return myDict

currentMoves = northOfHouse()
while 1:
    action = raw_input()
    if(action in currentMoves):
        currentMoves = currentMoves[action]()
    else:
        print "Invalid Input"
```

[Try Here on repl.it](https://repl.it/HQJz)

Comment: The more I build on this, the more I want to just built it into something huge, but I think classes and nested dictionaries are a bit beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you Nick A, That worked. Also, moving the dictionary below my definitions allowed the value northOfhouse to be defined.

Comment: @Darwin, I wasn't sure of the structure of the rest of your code but yes that couldve been an issue, dont forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.