# python locals() redundant usage

Tags: python

Hi I am kinda new to using locals(), I did research that locals() means treat a variable within a function as a dictionary. We have a bunch if this function with the same function of locals() below. I am man of DRY principle but in this area its not. How will I simplify this or any alternative way?

```
def home_creation(self, property, item):
    def date(data):
        return data
    def rate(data):          
        return data

    if property in locals():
        return locals()[property](item)
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Don't use `locals` for this, just define your own dictionary, or use `if-elif-else`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, why dont use locals? How can you do it alternatively?

Comment: use a `dict` of functions. See Uriel's answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga also seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168340/using-a-dictionary-to-select-function-to-execute

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own dictionary to limit the permitted methods for use:

```
def home_creation(self, property, item):
    def date(data):
        return data
    def rate(data):          
        return data

    functions = {
        'date': date,
        'rate': rate
    }

    return functions.get(property, lambda: None)(item)
```

Comment: Sorry dont quite get what you mean.  This function is under a class by the way.