# All keys are getting selected in dictionary python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, switch-statement

I am trying to write a switch case using a dictionary, and calling functions from them all. But the `{key,value}` pairs are all being printed:

```
def addWord():
    print "Add word"

def searchWord():
    print "Search word"

def displayAll():
   print "display all"


#Executing the choice
def switch_choice(choice):
    switcher = {
            1:addWord(),
            2:searchWord(),
            3:displayAll()
    }.get(choice,"Invalid input")


#MAIN
print "Enter your choice"
print "1.Add new word"
print "2.Search for a word"
print "3.Display all words"

choice=input()

switch_choice(choice)
```

Output -

```
Enter your choice
1.Add new word    
2.Search for a word
3.Display all words
1
Add word
Search word
display all
```

Can anyone please let me know the reason.

Comment: You are calling functions instead of holding a reference to them

Comment: Note: you are using Python 2, not 3, or you'd have syntax error problems with those `print` statements.

Comment: See the second linked answer  here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168387/4909087

Comment: If using python 3, you'd also have a problem because input returns a string, and '1' != 1

Comment: Sorry for the python 3 tag, I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not storing functions. You are storing the *results* of the function calls. Do not call the function objects, call the result of the `dict.get()` call:

```
switcher = {
    1: addWord,
    2: searchWord,
    3: displayAll,
}.get(choice, lambda: "Invalid input")()
```

In Python, functions are just objects, and the `()` part is just a piece of syntax you can apply to any expression; as long at the expression produces something that is callable (like a function object), then Python is fine with that.

Note that I gave the `dict.get()` method a `lambda` expression for the default; if the `choice` value is not a key in the dictionary, you still need to return something that is callable.