# Overriding not working when calling method using reference name

Tags: python

My primary goal was to have a dictionary to select method to run. It was easy to do per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168387/1750360) suggestion.
But now I am somehow blocked on using the inheritance concept to call child overridden method.

```
class A():
    def sum(self, id: int):
        return 1

    def multiply(self, id: int):
        return 2

    def process(self, type: str, id: int):
        callable_method = self.__dispatcher.get(type)
        return callable_method(self, id) # Runs
        #callable_method(id)      # Doesnt work with my object, says parameter mismatch
        #self.callable_method(id) # Doesn't Work obviously as there is no callable method in self

    __dispatcher = { "+": sum,  "*": multiply  } 

class B(A):
    def process(self, type: str, id: int):
        return super(B, self).process(type, id)

    def multiply(self, id: int):
        return 3

# main class call:
    ob = B()
    ob.process("*", 0)  # This is returning 2 instead of 3
```

The above overriding works perfectly well if I dont use the dictionary and method references and directly use the method in parent's process() like `self.multiply(id)`

I might have an idea why this is not working but is there a way to make this work in Python?

Note:

- Dont want to use exec() , eval() due to security issues
- I'm not trying to write a calculator, actual problem is related to software design
- using Python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because `A.__dispatcher` is defined when `A` is first defined, and `A.__dispatcher['*']` is a reference to `A.multiply`. You instead want something like

```
def __init__(self):
   self.__dispatcher = {'*': self.multiply}
```

Alternatively,

```
def get_dispatcher(self):
   return {'*': self.multiply}
```

and you use `self.get_dispatcher()` in place of `__dispatcher`

Comment: This worked and using self.func_name as values in dictionary even saved me from passing the self reference again. Thanks.