# Understanding functions in dictionaries

Tags: python, function, dictionary

```
#Creating all the arithmetic functions
def add(n1, n2):
    added_number = n1 + n2
    return added_number

def substract(n1, n2):
    substracted_number = n1 - n2
    return substracted_number

def multiply(n1, n2):
    multiplied_number = n1 * n2
    return multiplied_number

def divide(n1, n2):
    divided_number = n1 / n2
    return divided_number

#Making a dictionary with the operation as the key and the functions as the values
operations = {
    "+": add,
    "-": substract,
    "*": multiply,
    "/": divide,
}
```

This is not exactly a problem, but I'm not able to understand how functions work in dictionaries.

I'm trying to make a simple calculator program but I don't understand why we don't add parentheses () after the values in the dictionary. Why isn't it running into an error? I haven't even used quotations.

After this I'm supposed to call the functions with:

```
symbol(2, 3) = operations[+]
```

How does this thing work exactly? Why am I calling the function with another variable, how is that possible?

I have tried watching various videos but still I'm not able to wrap my head around this.

Comment: `operations['+']`, rather. `operations[+]` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: `operations['+']()`

Comment: That said, `symbol(2,3) = operations[+]` doesn't make any sense; you can't assign to a function call. What you _can_ do is call `operations['+'](2,3)`

Comment: If you have defined `add` as a function, then you can use it directly via `add(2, 3)`.  If you put it in a dictionary, with the key `"+"`, then `operations["+"]` is exactly the same thing as `add`, and `operations["+"](2, 3)` is how you'd call it.  Your example of "how you're supposed to call it" is nonsense, I don't know where you got that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a dictionary to select function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168340/using-a-dictionary-to-select-function-to-execute)  The question is a bit different but answers should give you good explanation.

Comment: The idea (which is probably the part missing from your example) is to be able to *map* from user input (i.e. `+` type str) to the function to obtain the result

Comment: Functions are [first-class objects](https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/FunctionsSolutions.html) in python. This means a function is just like any other object you might have. You _call_ the function using parentheses after its name, but if you specify just the name, you have a "reference" to the function.

Answer (score -2):

A function is just a piece of code that exists in memory, just like a class or a variable is, so it can be pointed to, just like any other variable (lists, integers, etc.). Imagine the "normal" case: `add(2,3)` this calls the function `add` on parameters `(2,3)`, but the `add` is just a pointer to the bytecode of the function in memory.

Now instead of directly calling the function, you can store its reference (pointer) in a dictionary, this exists in C++ as well (function pointers). Using the example code you provided, when you look up `operations['+']` you get back the function pointer for `add`, which can be called with some parameters like `operations['+'](2,3)`. If you store the function "with parenthesis" in the dictionary, instead of getting back a function pointer, you get back the result of the function execution

```
operations = {'+':add(2,3)}
print(operations['+']) # Prints 5, which is the result of add(2,3)
```

You get back whatever you put in the dictionary, be it a list, integer, function pointer, or result of function execution.

This means you can even define partial functions using `lambda` or `functools.partial` since each "partial function" has a function pointer and some populated arguments.

Comment: I think you meant to write `{'+': add(2, 3)}`. But this performs the calculation when creating the dictionary, not when you look up the dictionary value.

Comment: @JonSG sorry I missed the add before the paranthesis

Comment: @Barmar that was my point, in one case you store the result of the computation, and in another case you store the function pointer

Comment: Sorry, was just focusing on the typo in the code, didn't read the text.