# How to use python in command line as pipe?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pipe

I want to use python as a pipe in the command line mode. I tried some ways like this:

```
ls -la | python -c "import sys; for line in sys.stdin: print(line[0])"
```

But it didn't work:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; for e in sys.stdin: print(e[0])
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about this: `"import sys\nfor line in sys.stdin:\n\tprint(line[0])"`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It didn't work. `SyntaxError`

Comment: I was able to get it to work with this syntax - `python -c $'import sys;\nfor line in sys.stdin: print(line[0])'`. I had help from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23301247/558021). Note the addition of `\n` and the `$` character.

Comment: you can use also exec: `ls -la | python3 -c 'exec("import sys\nfor e in sys.stdin:\n\tprint(e[0])")'`