# Weird newline character error in python

Tags: python, linux, shell, newline

I've been trying to use the linux shell to output a sequence of bytes into a file using Python. The problem is when I do:

```
python -c "print '\x11\x22\x33\x44'" > new_file
```

The new_file contains '\x11\x22\x33\x44\x0a'.

I looked up similar questions here on StackOverflow and tried to strip out the \x0a by the following and many other similar techniques:

```
python -c "print '\x11\x22\x33\x44'.rstrip('\x0a')" > new_file
```

The \x0a, however, refuses to go.

Has anyone run into this problem before? Would really appreciate a quick fix. Thanks.

PS: I've tried this with various versions of Python including 2.5, 2.7, 3.1, 3.3. All lead to the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `print` function automatically adds a newline character at the end (ascii `0x0a`). You can use the Python 3 version of `print` to set the end character:

```
> python3 -c "print('\x11\x22\x33\x44', end='')" > new_file
> hexdump -C new_file
11 22 33 44
```

If you really need to use Python 2, you can use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2043499/2679935) to run a multiline Python code in your terminal:

```
echo -e "import sys\nsys.stdout.write('\x11\x22\x33\x44')" | python > new_file
```

Comment: or even fewer characters: `python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('\x11\x22\x33\x44')" > new_file`

Comment: Thanks guys. This works perfectly. Just wondering though, why does 'print' a 0x0a but stdout.write doesn't? Is it because the print function assumes its arguments to be strings?