# Python one liner silent socket listener

Tags: python, sockets

Is it possible to write python one-liner, which will be listen on specific tcp port, accept connections, and response nothing.

I can do this in two lines:

```
import socket; s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM); s.bind(("", 5555)); s.listen(1); accepter = s.accept();
while True: data = accepter[0].recv(1024);
```

But I want to run this from `python -c`, So it should be one line.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043453/executing-python-multi-line-statements-in-the-one-line-command-line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) (In Python 3.x, you need to use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)):

```
import socket, itertools; s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM); s.bind(('', 5555)); s.listen(1); accepter = s.accept(); reduce(lambda x, y: accepter[0].recv(1024), itertools.count())
```

You can also use other infinite iterator like [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) or [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat).

Following lines are an expanded version of above one-liner.

```
import socket, itertools
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 5555))
s.listen(1)
accepter = s.accept()
reduce(lambda x, y: accepter[0].recv(1024), itertools.count())
```

Comment: @kingsdeb, With `-c` option python interpret the given string as a program content.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "socket.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM); s.bind(("", 5555)); s.listen(1); accepter = s.accept()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INET'

Comment: @kingsdeb, What is you python version? What is your platform?

Comment: Python 2.7.5 on Fedora 20

Comment: @kingsdeb, It should work. I tested this in Python 2.7.6/3.4.0 in Ubuntu 14.10 and in Python 2.7.8/3.4.1 in Windows 7. http://asciinema.org/a/11870

Comment: yeah it works, I got that error because i had a file socket.py in the working dir. Removing the .py and .pyc files make it work.. It was so stupid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60405/discussion-between-kingsdeb-and-falsetru).