# Python socket listener keep down

Tags: python, sockets

I have python project. The project is listening a port. Here is my code:

```
import socket

conn = None     # socket connection

###
#   port listener
#   @return nothing
###
def listenPort():
     global conn
     conn = socket.socket()
     conn.bind(("", 5555))
     conn.listen(5)
```

After run my app I checked with [hercules](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html) for port connection. It works but I disconnected and again connected. after doing it **5 time** connection return error. I want to the listener must works always. How can I got app like I want ? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I will run my app only on server and I will check by [Uptime root](https://uptimerobot.com/) listener is working.

Comment: I saw [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609467/python-one-liner-silent-socket-listener), but I didn't understand anything. Maybe It is not What I search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is normal :

- you listen to a socket with a queue of size 5
- you never accept any connection

=> you enqueue 5 connection requests and the 6th causes an error.

You must **accept** a request to remove it form the listen queue and work with it (the command `accepter = conn.accept()` derived from related post)

Edit

Here is a fully functionnal example :

```
def listenPort():
    global conn
    conn = socket.socket()
    conn.bind(("", 5555))
    conn.listen(5)
    while True:
        s, addr = conn.accept() # you must accept the connection request
        print("Connection from ", addr)
        while True:  # loop until othe side shuts down or close the connection
            data = s.recv(17)   # do whatever you want with the data
            # print(data)
            if not data:  # stop if connection is shut down or closed
                break
            # for example stop listening where reading keyword "QUIT" at begin of a packet
            # elif data.decode().upper().startswith("QUIT"):
            #     s.close()
            #     conn.close()
            #     return
        s.close() # close server side
```

Comment: Now I got error `accepter = conn.accept()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\socket.py", line 132, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
socket.error: [Errno 10022] Received an invalid argument`

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich This is a weird error : I've just looked at the manual and the syntax is indeed `fd, addr = conn.accept()` where `conn` is a bound and listening socket. I've currently no access to my computer, but I'll try that in a while.

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich : I could test and it works. Server side : `conn = socket.socket() - conn.bind(("", 5555")) - conn.listen(5) - conn.accept()` (` - ` standing for new line) - client side : `s = socket.socket() - s.connect(("localhost, 5555))` . Server side `accept` waits until client side `connect`.

Comment: I just want to listener in server side and I don't care about client side. I use [uptime root](https://uptimerobot.com/)  to check my listener is working or not

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich : I've added an example tested under python 3.4

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich : the error you showed in first comment was probably caused by calling `accept` before `listen`