# Conditional Statements using "cmd python -c" — How can I pass `if`?

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I have written a batch script that prompts the user for an input and displays the help for a specific library `ExternalLibrary`. However, I receive the error below the code sample.

```
@echo off
set input=NUL
set /p input="Help: "

python -c "import sys; sys.path.append('D:\\lib'); import ExternalLibrary;lookup = ExternalLibrary.Presentation_control();if ('%input%' == 'NUL'):&    help(lookup.%input%)&else:&    help(lookup)"
```

A working version can be achieved by replacing the `if` statement with:

```
help(lookup.%input%)
```

---

Error in the column that starts with `if`

```
C:\Users\usah>Lib_Help.cmd
Help:
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; sys.path.append('D:\\lib'); import ExternalLibrary;lookup = ExternalLibrary.Presentation_control();if ('NUL' == 'NUL'):&    help(lookup.NU
L)&else:&    help(lookup)
                                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

<sub>**Footnotes**</sub>

<sub>1. I am note sure whether I should pass `&`, `\n`, or `;` as newline</sub>

<sub>2. These [related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043453/executing-python-multi-line-statements-in-the-one-line-command-line) are not satisfying as they use workarounds.</sub>

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: That does not work

Comment: But the error message is different, right?

Comment: Nope. I am afraid not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Only simple statements can be written on single line separated by semicolons

This was more interesting than it seemed. For the sake of unambiguity you can't write conditional or any other compound statement on semicolon separated single line.

[Simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html)

[Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html)

## Your options

### Rewrite it all to Python

This should not be so hard. Use `sys.argv` for arguments and

```
getattr(lookup, "something")
```

instead of your

```
lookup.%input%
```

[sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

[getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

### Use linefeeds

Write multiline Python script on one cmd line. You can do it using `!LF!` special.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


set input=NUL
set /p input="Help: "


python -c "import sys!LF!sys.path.append('D:\\lib')!LF!import ExternalLibrary!LF!lookup = ExternalLibrary.Presentation_control()!LF!if ('%input%' == 'NUL'):!LF!    help(lookup)!LF!else:!LF!    help(lookup.%input%)!LF!"
```

Comment: Great answer! I corrected some errors in my code. The code you provided is now runnable!