# Execute python within bash script

Tags: python, bash, unix, centos, webserver

I need to execute the following code from within a shell script. Typically in languages such as node.js I could write `node -e "code here"` to execute the code. How can I replicate this functionality with Python?

```
# Python server
python "import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
PORT = $pythonPort
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()"
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use a [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

For example, here's a simple test script:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
testnum=$1

if [ -z $testnum ]; then
    testnum=-1.1
fi

python <<EOF
import math
print(math.fabs($testnum))
EOF
```

You could do the same thing by putting your python logic in a separate  python script (that takes commandline args) and then just calling it in your shell script.  For example:

```
python test.py $testnum
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can*... it's very confusing (at least it is for me) as soon as you get more than... 3 lines, but you can. For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Python server
pythonPort=8000
python -c "import SimpleHTTPServer;"`
`"import SocketServer;"`
`"PORT = $pythonPort; "`
`"print(PORT); "`
`"Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler; "`
`"httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer((\"\", PORT), Handler); "`
`"print(\"serving at port %s\" % PORT); "`
`"httpd.serve_forever()"
```

The important part is the `-c` (to run the text after it as a command passed to the interpreter)

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043453/executing-python-multi-line-statements-in-the-one-line-command-line).

I'd put that in a file if possible, though. If you need the ability to make the port configurable, you can use [`sys.argsv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) in your Python code and pass it in the command call as an argument.

For instance, put this in a script:

*run_server.py*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python server
import sys
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = int(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv)
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print("serving at port %s" % PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And call it with `python ./run_server.py 8000` The content of `sys.argv` is a list, where the first item is the script's name, and then the rest are the arguments passed in the call. In this example's case, that would be: `['./run_server.py', '8000']`