# with ... : for ... : in a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

As a beginner python programmer, I am hoping this is some stupid error (or lack of understanding) that has an simple solution:

```
/tmp> python3 -c 'with open("t","r") as f: for l in f: print(l)'
  File "<string>", line 1
    with open("t","r") as f: for l in f: print(l)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I can embed a newline in the oneline, but trying to understand why the above does not work

```
/tmp> python3 -c $'with open("t","r") as f:\n for l in f: print(l)'
Hi there
```

Comment: Why not `print '\n'.join(l for l in open("t"))`?

Comment: You cannot have two *statements* in the same line.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043453/executing-python-multi-line-statements-in-the-one-line-command-line

Comment: Or, `python -c "print ''.join(open('t').readlines())"`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, sure you can. For example, `if True: import math; pass; assert 2+2==4` has four statements on the same line.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, you are correct, the term I needed to use was *simple statement*. Er, rather, you can't have two non-simple statements or non-small statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Full grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), the only statements you're allowed to put immediately after a `with` statement on the same line, are statements in the `simple_stmt` class.

Relevant parts of the grammar:

```
with_stmt: 'with' with_item (',' with_item)*  ':' suite
suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
             import_stmt | global_stmt | nonlocal_stmt | assert_stmt)
flow_stmt: break_stmt | continue_stmt | return_stmt | raise_stmt | yield_stmt
```

In plainer language, these statements appear to be:

- Expression statements
- del
- pass
- break
- continue
- return
- raise
- yield
- import
- global
- nonlocal
- assert

`for` is not part of this list, so it is not allowed to come immediately after a `with` with no intervening newline.