# How to convert a shell script (bash) to Scala code?

Tags: scala, processbuilder

I have a shell script with series of defined steps. I am trying to convert the script to Scala code by maintaining the order of steps. Basically I want my Scala code to be a mirror of the shell script.

I've used **sys.process._** library. 
The shell script has commands like:

```
mkdir <pathToDir>
hadoop fs -copyToLocal <source> <dest>
rm -r <pathToDir>
java -jar <someScript>
```

I need to maintain the order of execution of these steps.

I tried something like:

```
import sys.process._
Class A {
  def processMethod(): Unit = { 
    Process("mkdir -p <dir1>") #| Process("hadoop fs -copyToLocal 
    <hdfsDir1> <localDir1>") #| Process("mkdir -p <dir2>") #| 
    Process("hadoop fs -copyToLocal <hdfsdir2>/*.parquet <localDir2>") 
    #| Process("java -jar <pathToJarFile> -script <sampleScripts> 1>&2") 
    #| Process("rm -r<localDir1>") #| Process("rm -r <localDir2>") ! 
  }
}
```

I'm expecting the operations to execute in the order they have been defined. I'm confused about how ProcessBuilder/Process works or if there is an alternative to convert this whole thing to Scala code?

Comment: Ammonite bills itself as bash replacement: http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-Shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [document](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html#|(other:scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder):scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder), `#|` constructs a command that will run command and pipes the output to other.
Thats being said, the following code in Scala:

```
(Process("echo hello") #| Process("wc -c")).!
```

is equivalent to following Bash code:

```
echo hello | wc -c
```

which is not what you want.

What you are looking for is [###](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html####(other:scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder):scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder) operator which constructs a command that will run one command and then other.

Using this operator, you can do write following Scala code:

```
(Process("ls") ### Process("echo hello")).!
```

Which is equivalent to following Bash code:

```
ls
echo hello
```

However, note that using `Process` in the way above is not completely bash equivalent because it cannot change current directory with `cd` nor use bash syntax such as `if`, `for`, `case`.

If you really want bash equivalent code, the only way is running the script with bash.

Comment: Ammonite has a notion of working dir. http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-Shell

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `###` method, as @ymonad has pointed out, you should really be using the `ProcessBuilder` methods more directly. It makes the code easier to read and understand.

```
import sys.process._

Seq("mkdir", "SO")        ###
Seq("touch", "SO/file")   ###
Seq("mv", "SO", "SoWhat") !
```

Using a `Seq[String]` in place of a simple `String` offers [some advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54330536/4993128) when parsing multiple arguments passed to the process.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't digged into this project so I can't help you with a first-hand example, but have a look at the [Ammonite Scala project](http://ammonite.io/).

Quoting from the home page:

> Ammonite lets you use the Scala language for scripting purposes: in the REPL, as scripts, as a library to use in existing projects, or as a standalone systems shell.
>
> ...
>
> The goal of Ammonite is to liberate your Scala code from heavyweight "projects", using the lightweight Ammonite runtime: if you want to run some Scala, open the Ammonite-REPL and run it, interactively! If you want to run it later, save it into some Scala Scripts and run those later.

[At this link](http://ammonite.io/#Operations) are some examples of what you can do:

```
import ammonite.ops._

// Let's pick our working directory
val wd: Path = pwd/'ops/'target/"scala-2.11"/"test-classes"/'example3

// And make sure it's empty
rm! wd
mkdir! wd

// You can create folders through `mkdir!`. This behaves the same as
// `mkdir -p` in Bash, and creates and parents necessary
val deep = wd/'this/'is/'very/'deep
mkdir! deep

// You can also use backticks to execute commands which aren't valid Scala identifiers, e.g.
`ssh-add`
Enter passphrase for /Users/haoyi/.ssh/id_rsa:
```