# I am having trouble running a bash script that opens docker container in interactive mode and eexcute some commands

Tags: spring, bash, docker, tomcat

I am using next commands to open a docker container in interactive mode and using following commans inside bash session with this container.

```
  docker run -v /scriptsIA:/scriptsIA -v /opt/tomcat/webapps/PokeTrainer/imgIA:/imgsIA -it dbmobilelife/docker-python-opencv-tesseract bash

cd /scriptsIA/

python

from SegmentarImagen import *

extraerNombreUsuarioNiveldeUnaFoto("/imgsIA/andres.jpg")

exit()

exit
```

I have tried to create a bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -v /scriptsIA:/scriptsIA -v /opt/tomcat/webapps/PokeTrainer/imgIA:/imgsIA -it dbmobilelife/docker-python-opencv-tesseract bash
cd /scriptsIA/
python
from SegmentarImagen import *
extraerNombreUsuarioNiveldeUnaFoto("/imgsIA/andres.jpg")
exit()
exit
```

However, when i execute this bash script all i get is the following error:

> [root@poketrainer /]# sh scriptIA.sh docker: Error response from
>   daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"bash\r\": executable file not found
>   in $PATH": unknown. : No existe el fichero o el directorio
>   scriptIA.sh: línea 4: $'python\r': no se encontró la orden
>   scriptIA.sh: línea 5: from: no se encontró la orden scriptIA.sh: línea
>   6: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado
>   `"/imgsIA/andres.jpg"' 'criptIA.sh: línea 6:`
>   extraerNombreUsuarioNiveldeUnaFoto("/imgsIA/andres.jpg")

How can I do the explained bash script above withouth getting errors?

Comment: I would make the script part of the container. Then you don't need interactive mode and you can execute it by default when someone starts the container.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your script here:

The `\r` errors such as:

> starting container process caused "exec: **\"bash\r\":** executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

And other similar errors are related: the `\r` indicates there is a Windows carriage return in your script - it was probably written on Windows and mounted in a VM, or your editor somehow added these characters (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043453/executing-python-multi-line-statements-in-the-one-line-command-line)). Linux only expects a `\n` and treats `\r`as part of your command. Try running `dos2unix` on your file or make sure there are no special characters.

---

Also, the script has several issues:

- You are trying *to run docker exec which runs a bash command which cd and runs a python script.* This can be simplified a bit (see below)
- You want to run Python, there is probably no need to run `bash` first, you can run `python` command directly
- Given that you want to run 2 Python commands you'll require line breaks, [that's possible but not very handy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043453/executing-python-multi-line-statements-in-the-one-line-command-line). It would be better to create a Python script and mount it in the image before running a simple python command.
- It would also be better to use [docker exec `-w` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#usage) instead of using `cd` command to set working directory
- There is no need for exit nor exit() as it will be done implicitly once there are no more instructions to be executed

Given all that, you can:

- run a single command such as

  ```
  docker exec [...] -it -w /scriptsIA dbmobilelife/docker-python-opencv-tesseract \
       echo -e "from SegmentarImagen import *\nextraerNombreUsuarioNiveldeUnaFoto("/imgsIA/andres.jpg")" | python
  ```

  in which you set working directory with `-w` and run a Python command by passing its content via echo and a pipe (mind the `\n` with no space to have a proper Python syntax)
- creating a `myscript.py` script such as:

  ```
  from SegmentarImagen import *
  extraerNombreUsuarioNiveldeUnaFoto("/imgsIA/andres.jpg")
  ```

  then mount that script into the container and run a simple python command:

  ```
  docker exec [...] -it -w /scriptsIA -v /path/to/myscript.py:/myscript.py \
     dbmobilelife/docker-python-opencv-tesseract \
     python /myscript.py
  ```

*Note: the [...] are for the `-v /scriptsIA:/scriptsIA -v /opt/tomcat/webapps/PokeTrainer/imgIA:/imgsIA` volume mount I cut out for simplification*