# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position

Tags: python, windows, unicode

I saw here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35651859/6824121 that you can launch python script directly in your terminal in **windows** like this:

```
> python -c exec("""import sys \nfor r in range(10): print('rob') """)
```

Which works perflectly.

I tried to launch this command:

```
> python -c exec("""test = r'C:\Users\alexa\Downloads\_internal'""")
```

And I got error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 11-12: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

As in this question ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

But I used `raw string` so I don't know why I still got the error.

What am I missing here ?

I'm using `Python 3.6.8` even though I don't think this is related to the version of python.

Comment: `"""..."""` is not a raw string, you need to also prepend that with `r`, i.e. `r"""test = r'C:\Users\alexa\Downloads\_internal'"""`

Answer (score 0):

For this code to work properly, you have to prefix the string with the character `r`. This is crucial, as it turns the string into a raw string. This is needed, as this treats the backslash character (`/`) as a literal character. This is why this code will work:

```
> python -c exec(r"""test = r'C:\Users\alexa\Downloads\_internal'""")
```

This is also why the `r` character is needed inside of the string as well, as when that code is executed it will be needed for the same purpose.

You can also (though I do not recommend this) use double backslashes, which escape the first backslash. This is hard to read, however, and makes it easy to make mistakes. For example:

```
> python -c exec("""test = r'C:\\Users\\alexa\Downloads\\_internal'""")
```

In the end I would recommend the raw string, however.

Hope this helps.